# Office 365 Email Trigger when new mail arrives does not fire as required in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, office365, azure-logic-apps

I am witnessing quite recently that my Logic App which doesn't fire when a new Mail arrives. It's originally set to look every 1 minute, but regrettably, it doesn't fire at all; sometimes it fires after a big-time lapse.

This Logic App is set to look at any emails which arrive having an attachment of mostly less than 10KB files and the attachment type is *.csv. I am pretty sure I have not breached and office 365 limitations. Further, this Mailbox which is associated with this logic app is also linked with few other Logic apps to trigger when a new email arrives.

> What I did so far to resolve this issue:
>
> 1. Decreased time to check new emails from 1 Minute to 45 Seconds
> 2. Added the Time-Zone
> 3. Changed the Email account
> 4. Press the `Run Trigger` button manually

but nothing seems to work except for point 4; where pressing the `Run Trigger` button manually fetches the new emails and the workflow continues.

Did anybody face this issue lately?

[image]

Comment: Seems like V2 is [deprecated] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#triggers)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [hiFI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1479132/hifi). Posting your suggestions as answer to help other community members.

As **When new email arrives V2** is deprecated try using  **When new email arrives V3**

[image]

Check the [Deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#triggers) for further information